# Unable to attach one of the projects to the Process in C# debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I have multiple projects in a solution written in C#.

When trying to debug the code, I am attaching to the process of my application.
I am able to hit all the projects in the solution except few.

Everytime it says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit."

I tried all the approaches from the following link:

https://qawithexperts.com/article/asp-net/solving-error-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-in-vi/257

None of them worked.

Any other approaches I should check on? I am working on VisualStudio 2019 Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0):

I find that in this scenario you need to do a Build > Rebuild Solution in order to rebuild the project. You then Run Debug and attach to the process again